# Django – filter all products that have only empty variations

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

as the title says I'm trying to filter out all Products where all variations have a stock_quantity of 0. The variations are a separate class with a foreignkey to the Product. The related_name is set to 'variations'.

Here is my attempt:

```
Product.objects.annotate(variations_count=Count('variations')).filter(variations__stock_quantity=0)
```

However, it seems that filters out all variations where `at least` one variation has a stock quantity of 0, not all of them.

Here are my models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    ...


class Variation(models.Model):
    for_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='variants')
    stock_quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share your models.

Comment: Sorry for not doing earlier, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the *sum* of the quantities is zero, so:

```
from django.db.models import Sum


Product.objects.alias(
    stock_variations_count=Sum('variations__stock_quantity')
).filter(stock_variations_count=0)
```

or you can just exclude a `Product` that has any variant greater than zero:

```
from django.db.models import Sum


Product.objects.exclude(stock_variations__stock_quantity__gt=0)
```

the two are not entirely the same for `Product`s with *no* variant.

or if you want to filter this *out*, you use:

```
from django.db.models import Sum


Product.objects.alias(
    stock_variations_count=Sum('variations__stock_quantity')
).filter(stock_variations_count__gt=0)
```